# In flutter gesture detector, Is there a way to get delta?

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

Flutter ScaleUpdateDetails has no delta.

I want to get delta as if in DragUpdateDetails.

DragUpdateDetails seems to having     `this.sourceTimeStamp, this.delta = Offset.zero, this.primaryDelta, required this.globalPosition, Offset? localPosition,`

and ScaleUpdateDetails:

```
this.focalPoint = Offset.zero,
Offset? localFocalPoint,
this.scale = 1.0,
this.horizontalScale = 1.0,
this.verticalScale = 1.0,
this.rotation = 0.0,
this.pointerCount = 0,
```

So.. I want to delta from on scaleupdate.

I tried to use both onScaleUpdate and onPanUpdate, It was not allowed...

```
The following assertion was thrown building DraggableCard(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, _EffectiveTickerMode], state: _DraggableCardState#0437c(ticker inactive)):
Incorrect GestureDetector arguments.

Having both a pan gesture recognizer and a scale gesture recognizer is redundant; scale is a superset of pan.

Just use the scale gesture recognizer.
```

Comment: it has `scale` property instead

Comment: @pskink How to use scale?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to get the difference in scale between each frame.

From comments within the Flutter source code:

"details.scale gives us the amount to change the scale as of the start of this gesture, so calculate the amount to scale as of the previous call to _onScaleUpdate."

In other words, you need to save the scale value each time your onScaleUpdate handler is called and simply substract it from the current scale value in order to get the scale difference for each frame.

Worth noting though, is that the scale value is always relative to the scale at the START of the gesture, which is 1.0.

So if you want the absolute scale difference after several consecutive scale gestures, you need to take the difference from the initial scaling value.

Hope this is clear, otherwise let me know and I'll provide some code.